# How to hide UITableViewCells while not violating AutoLayout constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm currently working on an app to learn iOS programming and Swift. I have a view which contains two main subviews, a MKMapView and a UITableView. When a certain annotation is selected in the MapView, I want certain cells in the TableView to be hidden. If the annotation is deselected the cells should reappear. Currently I do this by setting the height for the cells to be hidden to 0 and calling `tableView.beginUpdates()` `tableView.endUpdates()`, however this causes all kinds of AutoLayout constraints inside my custom cells to break. I've also tried to set the hidden property on the cell to true before setting the height to 0, but AutoLayout constraints are still being broken.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good way keep two different arrays as table view data source. The first have all your data that can be displayed. The second one is the truly array data source of the table view. When clicking the annotations, you can renew the second array (inserting or deleting the data that must be or not displayed) by taking the data from the first array. The table view will only be reloaded at the end.

Comment: This is how I implemented my ViewController at first, but I couldn't figure out how I could animate the disappearance of cells when the second array is updated. I'm open to suggestions about how I could animate that change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My 2 cents: just try to lower the priority of one of the conflicting constraints to a lower value, like UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh (750 if used in Interface Builder) or even lower, it depends on how you cell is composed.
It should be enough to give the auto layout system a hint about which constraint can be safely broken. Probably you will want to break the constraint that defines the distance from the bottom margin.

Comment: It was indeed the constrains that defined the distance from the bottom that was giving trouble. I replaced it with another constraint which results in the same layout. Thanks!

Comment: That's what I really did, changed the priority of the bottom constraints for each cell. and everything worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Implementing  `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` like below. also you need to set the height constraint to `0`

Objc version

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (shouldHideCell)
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
}
```

Swift version

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if shouldHideCell {
            return 0
        } else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
  }
```

Comment: Ah I should have been clearer about which constraints are broken. The constraints inside the cell are broken, when the height is set to 0. By the way, lines in Swift shouldn't end with a `;`.

Comment: I m not a swift developer. Now its been removed. When the cell the of auto layout enabled by default height constraint gets added to the content view of the cell. When you don't implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath()`, Constraint gets conflicted with your 0 constraint view of subview

Comment: I fixed the problem by replacing a certain constraint with a less constrictive one which still gets the job done, thanks for the help though.

Comment: This still raises constraints issues!